# Unable to connect the SQL server using java programming

Tags: java, sql-server

I am trying to connect the SQL Database using JAVA programming. But it popups the error as given below.

**"The TCP/IP connection to the host SERVER, port 1433 has failed. Error: connect timed out. Please verify the connection properties and check that a SQL Server instance is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port."**

Also, I have enabled the TCP/IP  and in IPALL 1433 port number was also added and restarted the SQL server. But still unable to connect using java programming it shows the same error as mentioned above.

Java coding to Connect SQL server database is given below :

```
public class NewMain {


public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER:1433;username=Mselvakumars;password=Welcome1345;databaseName=Loan;";

    try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        System.out.println(con);

    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I am unable to find the root cause of why the error is persisting, Server database Credentials are correct. I don't know whether I am missing something in the code. Also tried stack overflow suggestions for this issue.

Comment: Are you able to connect to database from host where Java code is running using other tools?

Answer (score 0):

try this one its work for me

logger.info("load the driver class");
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

```
        // create the connection object
        logger.info("create the connection object");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=dbname", "user",
                "password");
```